# How can I add more user?

Tags: users

Ubuntu 14.10 Desktop has been installed.

An account and a guest are seen on my User Account.

A button to add more user is deactivated.

What should I do to do?

HELLOVENUS Fantagio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open "System Settings" > "User Accounts" and click on the "Unlock" button in the top-right corner, enter your `sudo` password and the "+" button in the bottom-left corner will be enabled.

If you need more advanced features, you can also install `gnome-system-tools`: open a Terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and run:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, type in your password and, if prompted to do so, hit <kbd>y</kbd> to confirm. Then run `exit` to close the `Terminal`.

To run `gnome-system-tools`: open a Terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and run:

```
gnome-system-tools
```

Once done, close `gnome-system-tools` and run `exit` to close the Terminal.